# How do I pass an excel range into a c++ function that expects a double ptr

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I am new to vba and excel programming, so excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I have a c++ dll with a function

```
double foo(int n_bar, double* bar);
```

which I would like to call from excel using vba. I have declared the function in vba as

```
Declare Function foo Lib "mylib" (ByVal n_bar As Long, bar As Double) As Double
```

I have another wrapper function in vba that I will call from the spreadsheet

```
Function wrapper(a As Range) As Double
```

What does the body of the wrapper function have to look like to call the c++ function? My best guess was

```
Function wrapper(a As Range) As Double
    Dim retval As Double
    'after making sure there is only one column...
    retval = foo(a.Rows.Count, a.Cells(1,1))
End Function
```

but that doesn't work (compiles and runs, but yields bogus results).

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, but it ain't pretty:

```
Function wrapper(a As Range) As Double
    Dim tmp() as Double
    Redim tmp(a.Rows.Count -1)
    For Counter = 1 To a.Rows.Count
        tmp(Counter-1) = a.Cells(Counter,1).Value
    Next Counter
    wrapper = foo(a.Rows.Count, hist(0))
End Function
```

Why do ranges start at 1, but arrays start at 0?
Why does an array defined as

```
Dim a(5) as Double
```

have 6 elements?

If someone has a better way of doing this, please let me know

Comment: yeah that's how I've done it in the bad old days when I used to do this. You can use the Option command to gets arrays to index from 1 but I always felt that made things worse!

Comment: LOL you got caught by the ol' VBA 1 based array indices issue. It is just one of those things you have to remember (if you still have to work with VBA). btw your solution looks good, n1 Hans.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use byref when you declare your double parameter. Or even better define your C function to receive the double value as a value parameter.

Comment: Can't use pass-by-value since I am trying to pass an array
I thought ByRef is default if nothing else is specified?

Comment: How is the C code supposed to know how large the array is?  You're going to have to build an array in your VBA code, when passing one element of an array by reference, the C code can find following elements, but since the value here is a temporary, there aren't going to be any other values properly arranged near it in memory.

Comment: @hans I'm not sure about ByRef think you are right on reflection. But you also need to transfer from the Range object into a Double local variable before calling C++ function. Do this by reading the Value or Value2 property.

Comment: @David Adding the value or value2 keyword doesn't help
@Ben How do I build an array in VBA? Are the elements of VBA arrays going to be in consecutive memory like they are in C?

Comment: @hans you just need to read up on vba arrays. You'll have to fill them out before calling your dll. You'll have to pass the length too.

Comment: @hans yes they are consecutive just pass the first element to your byref parameter. Sorry I've taken so long to understand your problem.

Answer (score -2):

a.Cells(1,1) could be a String, a variant, whatever. So to ensure type safety try

```
foo(Cdbl(a.cells(1,1)))
```

Comment: VBA will convert to double automatically

Comment: also I think you want the Value or Value2 property of Cells(1,1)

Comment: This is not the answer. The question was how does the OP pass an array to a C++ based function. The answer should include how to correctly initialise and pass this array.

Comment: For my defense, the C++ function expected a Long and a double. I mixed up the return value for a sec, so I only had one argument. (Or was it changed?). Good that he figured it out though.